# Cross-domain XMLHttpRequest, Access-Control-Allow-Origin header and $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cross-domain

I need a script to deliver information to requesting-pages hosted on different domains, through XMLHttpRequest. There are many questions and answers on the subject, but none of the ones I found fully answered my questions.

Searching on the net brought me to find out that I must allow these domains through headers like
`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` or
`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com");`

As I need more than one external domain, but still I find `*` much too open, further researches brought me on solutions relying on server-side comparison of `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` with authorized values. (on StackOverflow: [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1653308/3872061) for instance)

BUT I found no mention of `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` in php manuel (http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.variables.server.php) and my tests revealed that this entry isn't always set.

**So my questions are:

- when is the `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` superglobal set?

- is it reliable globally?... or client browser dependant?**

It seems (but just empirically, from my tests / Firefox 34.0.5 & ios Safari) that it is only set when 'needed', ie when request actually comes from another domain.

See short code extract hereunder to help understand the need
- no header sent if `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` not defined
  (assuming it's effectively not a cross domain call, there shouldn't be any problem),
- send "allow" header if defined and belonging to an array of accepted domains.

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {// in case of cross domain ajax call
    $http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']; 
    if(in_array($http_origin, $ajaxAllowedDomains))
       { header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin"); }
}
```

Comment: We're not here to review your code. We're here to help fix someones  programming errors.

Comment: I'm not requiring code review. I simply can't find help in php's manual on a $_SERVER entry that's quoted in other SO questions/answers. I thought here was the place to ask other's help when encountering problems where documentation brought no help. Sorry if I'm thus mistaken...

Comment: edited to make clearer that the question is an information request on an (as far as i could see) undocumented php superglobal, and no code review request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when is the `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` superglobal set?

When the HTTP request includes an `Origin` header. Browsers will set one when making a cross-domain request with XMLHttpRequest.

> is it reliable globally?

It is in situations where you might want to set CORS response headers.

Comment: Thanks, searching on CORS enabled me to find all information i needed in the w3 specs (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)